# Promise in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have changed the env property of my url to test my code locally.. It seems the error call back is not even getting called. 
My code snippet-

```
        $scope.getfiles = function() {
        Api.file.query().$promise.then(
        function(result){ $scope.getfiles = result; },  //on success
        $scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling("Failed to get  File data.",true)  //on failure--> Always this line of  code is executing..
           );
         };
```

If I try writing other error function. It is not even getting called.

```
        $scope.getfiles = function(){
        Api.flatFile.query().$promise.then(
         function(result){ $scope.File = result; 
  },
      function (result) { // this block is not getting called
         if(result.status== 404){
         $scope.addErrorAlert("Service is down.Please try again later",true);
         return;
     }
 });
};
```

Can someone help me out this situation?

```
        FileServices.factory('Api', ['$res', '$loc',
        function($res, $loc){
        var contextPath = $loc.absUrl().split('/app/')[0];
        return {
        flatFile: $res(contextPath+'/app/config/flatFile/data', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
        save: {method:'POST'},
        })
        };
       }]);
```

Comment: could you verify that function getting called or not debugging it through developer console.? is there any error in console>

Comment: The angular promise library is `$q`

Comment: What is `API.file.query()`, and what are you wanting to achieve with it, please provide the code portion.

Comment: Please see my edited post..

Comment: API is a a service. and am trying to add error alert message when service is down. So locally i tried to change env property of url.

Answer (score 1):

The function probably doesn't get called in either way.
The problem here is that in the first case you do not define a function as a callback but immediately call the function itself

```
$scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling("Failed to get  File data.",true)
```

this is not a callback-definition but the immediate call of $scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling

So my idea is that no error occurs and thats why in the second case the error-function isn't called either

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are checking for the `status` incorrectly.
You should be accessing the second parameter of the `fail` callback:

```
  // ...
  ,
  function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) { 
     if(textStatus == 404){
        $scope.addErrorAlert("Service is down.Please try again later",true);
        return;
   }
 }
```

***Note:*** *There is no `file` key in the object that you're returning from `Api` service, and therefore it should be `flatFile` instead.*